# Android SQLiteOpenHelper - how does onUpgrade() work?

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade, database-migration

Clearly this question has been asked before, but despite looking at several responses, I'm still a bit unsure. The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) for the onUpgrade() method didn't really help either.

Does onUpgrade() get run for each version increment (i.e., from db_v1 to db_v3 onUpgrade() is run once for 1->2, then again for 2->3), or is it just run once (i.e., from db_v1 to db_v3 onUpgrade() is run once for 1->3);

My assumption is that it only is called once. In which case, would something like this work OK?

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    switch (oldVersion) {
    case 0:
        migrateDatabaseToVersion_1(db);
        migrateDatabaseToVersion_2(db);
        migrateDatabaseToVersion_3(db);
        break;
    case 1:
        migrateDatabaseToVersion_2(db);
        migrateDatabaseToVersion_3(db);
        break;
    case 2:
        migrateDatabaseToVersion_3(db);
        break;
    default:
        Log.d(LOG, "no database migrations necessary");
        break;
    }
}
```

I saw a response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14419630/1542275) that kind of suggest something similar, but using if statements instead of switch. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) doesn't say this explicitly, but it wouldn't make sense to give both the old and new version numbers as parameters if it would be called for each increment.

Note: it is preferrable to use a series of `if` statements instead of a `switch`: as long as the old version is smaller than the version for the n-th step, upgrade that step.
Not only does this avoid duplications, but also prevents you from forgetting a `break` ...

Comment: can you elaborate on how using if statements would avoid duplications? I'm trying to sort out how that would look but can't I'm having trouble doing so.