# How to upgrade an SQLite table in app without SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade, android-update-app

I have created a table in my app:

```
public  static SQLiteDatabase attendancedb = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Attendance", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

attendancedb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS attendance ( subName VARCHAR , attend VARCHAR, total VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY (subName))");
```

How can I add one more column (notes) in the table?

If I do this:

```
attendancedb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS attendance ( subName VARCHAR , attend VARCHAR, total VARCHAR,notes VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY (subName))");
```

the updated app is crashing on accessing the notes data,
but working if I reinstall the app.

Or will it be efficient to use Alter query for now and future pupose?

I have **not** used the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.

---

### ***Here's the Solution***

---

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, "Attendance", null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    if(checktable(sqLiteDatabase)==0){ //for old user
        try {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE attendance ADD notes VARCHAR;");
        }catch (Exception e){  //for new user

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE  attendance ( subName VARCHAR , attend VARCHAR, total VARCHAR,notes VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY (subName))");
        }
    }
    }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int old, int newVersion) {


}



int checktable(SQLiteDatabase db){

    try{
    Cursor c= db.rawQuery("SELECT notes FROM  attendance", null);


        return 1;
    }catch (Exception e){

        return 0;
    }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a field to an existing sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315997/adding-a-field-to-an-existing-sqlite-database)

Comment: @0X0nosugar No, that would require using the open helper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have used `SQLiteOpenHelper` in the first place.
Anyway, I recommend that you start using `SQLiteOpenHelper` now.

Since your old app did not set a version (with [PRAGMA user_version](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version)), the existing database file will have version 0, which is interpreted by `SQLiteOpenHelper` as empty, so it will call `onCreate`.

So your `onCreate` method must check if the `attendance` table already exists. If not, create the database from scratch; if yes, upgrade the table from version 0 to version 1.
(To add a column, use [ALTER TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html).)

All future upgrades can then use the normal `onUpgrade` mechanism.

Comment: Now if I use SQLiteOpenHelper then I have to change all code where I have used the database to read or write data?

Comment: After you've called `getReadableDatabase()`/`getWritableDatabase()`, you have the same `SQLiteDatabase` object. But the point is that the helper always checks for the version before opening the database.

Comment: Thank you, I did as you said. Checkout my solution  :)